# Absolutely no keyboard communication between Computer and board?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, startup, driver, kernel

So I was given an Early 2009 iMac which was running Snow Leopard. I went and tried to install DOSDUDES Catalina Patcher OS on the computer and it failed and all of a sudden I've lost all communication from computer to Keyboard. I mean no communication at all. I can't boot into recovery mode to wipe hard drive because I have no keyboard communication. I have absolutely no idea what this issue could be. Any ideas?

Here is what I have tried already to solve it and still to no avail...

1. Checked keyboard. Plugged into every other computer I have and it works fine.
2. No matter what USB port you plug into it doesn't work
3. Pulled the hard drive and installed a new SSD and RAM

I feel this is some sort of driver malfunction but since I have no keyboard connection I cannot even run terminal demands, boot into recovery, safe mode, disk utility, etc. when I turn computer on, I cannot do anything and I just get the Question mark Folder when turning computer on because I can't download an OS.

Is there any sort of external device I can plug in that can check kernel tasks, system info, anything that may be of help?

Nothing has worked so far... Please any information appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: If you hold down [Option] during boot, do you see the Boot Picker screen? Does the Caps Lock key light up at all at any point? If you plug in a USB mouse (not a trackpad), do you see the LED at the bottom of the mouse light up?

Comment: What kind of Recovery are you trying to boot? The 2009 iMacs do not have Internet Recovery. Snow Leopard does not have a Recovery partition to boot to. Have you tried a Snow Leopard DVD or flash drive equivalent? Have you tried an El Capitan installer flash drive? In other words, your Mac will look for something bootable and automatically boot from it without you using the keyboard.

Comment: Have you try a Reset Smc : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295 ?

Comment: DAVID - I've just been holding [command]+[R] to try to get into recovery. The computer has fresh SSD so no current OS to Boot off. I have the OS on a USB but can't get to disk Utility in order to import.                                                                JEAN- Yes I have tried SMC reset, didn't help.                                                       PION - Now this is weird..... So I held down [option] during reboot and now I have a mouse on screen that is usable but no menu, just a white screen. Yes when the keyboard is plugged in mouse LED has power and caps lock light is on